# Combobox dinâmico com Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

A ideia base é semelhante ao [combobox de estados e cidades](http://www.daviferreira.com/posts/populando-selects-de-cidades-e-estados-com-ajax-php-e-jquery), que ao selecionar um estado, o próximo select retorna as cidades referentes.

No meu caso eu não consigo listar esses campos no segundo select (que equivaleria as cidades).

Com os códigos a seguir, o unico acontecimento é que, ao selecionar qualquer um dos campos, o segundo select recebe um option com o nome de 'escolha', conforme o script de reset do JS.

Fiz um teste com o método **ListaFiltroPersonalizado** e o mesmo está retornando os dados corretamente, o problema se encontra na transição assíncrona.

Obs: O código é [baseado neste artigo](http://blog.brayanrastelli.com/combos-dependentes-codeigniter/).

Obs²: Sei que no option coloquei o valor 'teste'..

Seguem trechos de código:

**Redações (Controller)**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Redacoes extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index() {
    //Carregar o model
    $this->load->model('Read_model');

    $data['redacoes'] = $this->Read_model->ListaRedacoes('Matricula', 'asc');

    if ($this->input->post('frmFiltro')):
        $data['filtros'] = $this->Read_model->listaFiltroPersonalizado($this->input->post('frmFiltro'));
    endif;

    $this->template->load('base', 'home', $data);
}
}
```

**Read (Model)**

```
class Read_model extends CI_Model {

private $table = 'redacoes';

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function ListaRedacoes($sort = 'Data', $order = 'desc', $limit = null, $offset = null) {

    $this->db->order_by($sort, $order);

    if ($limit):
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    endif;

    $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
    return $query->result();
}

public function ListaFiltroPersonalizado($filtro) {
    $this->db->select($filtro);
    $this->db->join('aluno_2016', 'aluno_2016.matricula_aluno = redacoes.Matricula');
    $this->db->group_by($filtro);
    $this->db->order_by($filtro, 'asc');
    $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
    return $query->result();
}

public function FiltraRedacoes($campo, $filtro) {
    $this->db->join('aluno_2016', 'aluno_2016.matricula_aluno = redacoes.Matricula');
    $this->db->where($campo, $filtro);
    $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
}
}
```

**home (view)**

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></label>
            <select name="frmFiltro"  id="frmFiltroPersonalizado" class="form-control" required="required">
                <!--onchange="this.form.submit()"-->
                <option value="" selected>-- Selecione um filtro --</option> 
                <option value="Tipo">Tipo</option> 
                <option value="unidade_aluno">Unidade</option>
                <option value="periodo_aluno">Período</option>  
                <option value="nome_curso">Curso</option>  
                <option value="turma_aluno">Turma</option>  
                <option value="sala_aluno">Sala</option>  
                <option value="descricao_curso">Descricao curso</option>  
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></label>
            <select name="frmFiltroValor" id="frmFiltroPersonalizadoValor" class="form-control" requireds="required">
                <option value="" selected>-- Selecione --</option> 

                <?php foreach ($filtros as $filtro): ?>
                    <option value="">teste</option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </select>
        </div>                                        
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript (Ajax)**

```
var path = '<?= base_url(); ?>'
            $(function () {

                $("select[name=frmFiltro]").change(function () {

                    filtro = $(this).val();

                    if (filtro === '')
                        return false;

                    resetaCombo('frmFiltroValor');

                    $.getJSON(path + 'redacoes/filtro/' + filtro, function (data) {

                        var option = new Array();

                        $.each(data, function (i, obj) {

                            option[i] = document.createElement('option');
                            $(option[i]).attr({value: obj.id});
                            $(option[i]).append(obj.nome);

                                $("select[name='frmFiltroValor']").append(option[i]);

                            });

                        });

                    });

                });

                function resetaCombo(el) {
                    $("select[name='" + el + "']").empty();
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    $(option).attr({value: ''});
                    $(option).append('Escolha');
                    $("select[name='" + el + "']").append(option);
                }
```

**.htacess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Qual o problema, os options não são criados?

Comment: Exatamente. Tentei de diversas formas e já não sei se é devido ao meu controller que não envia as informações, ou então se é o ajax que não recebe.. Fui ao console e a requisição é feita normalmente, mas sempre é criado um option com o valor 'escolha'.

Comment: já tentou? `$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    $('select[name='frmFiltroValor']').append($('<option>', { 
        value: item.id,
        text : item.nome 
    }));
});`

Comment: Olá, bom dia! Acredito que a sintaxe informada esteja incorreta.. tentei de diversas formas substituir aqui e todas apresentam erro, tanto que travou todo meu js. Eu substitui o código informado por esse:
$.each(data, function (i, obj) {

                            option[i] = document.createElement('option');
                            $(option[i]).attr({value: obj.id});
                            $(option[i]).append(obj.nome);

                            $("select[name='frmFiltroValor']").append(option[i]);

                        });

Comment: @ThiagoBarros, tentou a sintaxe que eu sugeri? Tente explicar melhor o que você diz como "apresentaram erro". O erro está na montagem do dropdown? O erro está no JSON? Erro no JS? Qual o erro exatamente? Coloque as informações de debug que você tiver :)

Comment: Com o meu código atual não é apresentado erro. Porém, no segundo select é criado um option com o texto 'Escolha'. Eu tentei com sua sintaxe e além de não ter funcionado, parou minhas outras funções. Muito provavelmente eu estou substituindo o código de forma errada (acredito que seja), ou a sintaxe que informou-me está incorreta.

Comment: Então o seu retorno de JSON não está funcionando... já testou? o 'Escolha' tá aparecendo porque você chama o método `resetaCombo('frmFiltroValor');`. Tem como vc me falar qual o valor da variável `var path = '<?= base_url(); ?>'`?

Comment: Podemos abrir uma conversa no chat? Porque muito provavelmente iremos poluir os comentários de código. E após solucionarmos, um de nós posta a resposta aqui com o script correto. Pode ser?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46736/discussion-between-marllon-nasser-and-thiago-barros).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa ter um objeto JSON sólido para poder exibir no select de forma dinâmica. Um exemplo de JSON sólido para uma consulta X:

`[{"resultadoBusca": "teste"},{"resultadoBusca": "teste2"},{"resultadoBusca": "teste3"}]`

Tendo o json sólido, basta percorrer o array no JS e consolidar a informação dentro do seu select:

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) { $('#frmFiltroValor').append($('<option>', { value: i, text : item.resultadoBusca }));
```