# Combobox dinamico Ajax Codegniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Olá!

Eu já olhei [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157397/combobox-din%C3%A2mico-com-codeigniter-3) e não me atende.

Eu tenho um select chamado Banco, conforme abaixo e me traz o resultado OK:

```html
<select id="banco" class="banco form-control" name="sel_banco_id" >
    <option value="0" disabled selected >Selecione</option>
    <?php foreach ($banco as $banco) {
         echo '<option value="'.$banco->id.'">'.$banco->nome.'</option>';
    } ?>
</select>
```

Eu preciso fazer um select dinâmico e dependendo do banco selecionado, quero popular `<select id="carteira" class="form-control" name="sel_carteira" >`.

Minha tabela para a carteira é:

```html
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`banco_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`carteira` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`situacao` TINYINT(1) NULL,
```

Tenho o seguinte código ajax:

```js
function obter_carteira_ajax(id, aguardar) {
    //Limpar
    $("#carteira :gt(0)").remove();
    if (id > 0){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            async: !aguardar,   
     url: 'boleto/buscar_carteira' + id,
            success: (function (data) {
                $(data).each(function () {
                    //Adiciona                    
       $("#carteira").append("<option value='" + this.id + "'>" + this.codigo + "</option>");
                });
            }),
            error: (function (erro) {
                TrataErroAjax(erro);
            })
        });
    }
}
```

OU

```js
function obter_carteira_ajax(id) {
    var id=id;
     $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'boleto/buscar_carteira',
            data:{'id':id},
            success:function(data){
            //A próxima coisa que você quer fazer
        }
     });
}
```

Gostaria de saber como deve ser o código do **Controller** e **Model**, levando em consideração o código Ajax:

```html
public function buscar_carteira ()
{
    $id=$this->input->post('id',true);
    //Chamar Model
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia!
Eu resolvi da seguinte forma:

Ajax

```js
function obter_carteira_ajax(id) {
    var id = id;
 $("#carteira :gt(0)").remove();
 if(id > 0) {
     $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'boleto/buscar_carteira/' + id,
   dataType: "json",
            success:function(data){
    $('select[name="sel_carteira"]').empty();
    $.each(data, function(key, valor) {    
                $('select[name="sel_carteira"]').append('<option value="'+ valor.id +'">'+ valor.carteira + " " + valor.modalidade + '</option>');
            });
   error: (function (erro) {
                TrataErroAjax(erro);
            })
        }
    });
 } else {
        $('select[name="sel_carteira"]').empty();
 }
}
```

Controller

```html
public function buscar_carteira ($id)
 {  
       $result = $this->db->where("banco_id",$id)->get("tbl_carteira")->result();
       echo json_encode($result);
 }
```